# Map being skipped on array of objects

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out why my map is not resolving.  It's somehow skipping my map even though `countriesAtoH` shows me that it does have an array of objects in it but when I try to map over it, it's like it doesn't map it, because I can't put breakpoints inside map and map ultimately is not invoked.  Meaning I get a length of 0 on `options`

```
const countries = {
  Afghanistan: {
    countryId: 0,
      name: "Afghanistan"
    },
    Albania: {
      countryId: 1,
      name: "USA"
    },
    Algeria: {
      countryId: 99,
      name: "Canada"
    }
}


export const countryOptions = () => {
  let countriesAtoH = [];
  Object.keys(countries).forEach((c) => {
    if (countries[c].countryId <= 97) {
      countriesAtoH[c] = countries[c];
    }
  });

  const options = countriesAtoH.map(country => {
    const c = {
      text: {
        type: "plain_text",
        text: country.name,
      },
      value: country.countryId
    }
      return c;
    });

  return options;
}
```

[image]

Comment: what's `c`? (padding)

Comment: just because I don't need anything special just a simple name for the constant

Comment: and I want to be able to debug that instead of just returning the object

Comment: I mean if `c` is not number, options would be empty (since map doesn't count those)

Comment: c is just what I'm ultimately returning for the map on each iteration.  The problem is in the map, not the countryOptions

Comment: oh I re-read your code and it's definitely not number (it's string)

Comment: you cannot use `Array.map` that way.

Comment: you can map an array of objects, I do it all the time...

Comment: No, simply check it yourself `x = []; x["here"]=1; x.map(x=>x)`

Comment: *you can map an array of objects, I do it all the time...*. Yes, you can map an array of objects but not an array with non numerical indices.

Comment: gotcha, thianks @javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
countriesAtoH[c] = countries[c];
```

`c` is country name as string, not number as array index, so the country will not be push to the array. So the array is still empty as `Array(0)` in your log.
You may want to do array push here:

```
countriesAtoH.push(countries[c]);
```

Comment: hmm I did get an array of objects though see above

Comment: but oddly when I use .push yes then map works, I don't see why it made any difference if I ended up with an array of objects either way

Comment: But it's the empty array: `Array(0)`. The objects is assigned as properties of array variable, not the member of array with index. So map not work.

Comment: I'm lost at what you just said @thanhdx

Answer (score 0):

You have problems on `countriesAtoH[c] = countries[c]` part.

The type of `countriesAtoH` is `array` so the index should be the number and you are assigning `c` value (string) value as the index on `countriesAtoH` array.

Therefore, it is not working. It's better to set `countriesAtoH = {}` as object and use `Object.values(countriesAtoH)` on getting `options` variable.

```js
const countries = {
  Afghanistan: {
    countryId: 0,
    name: "Afghanistan"
  },
  Albania: {
    countryId: 1,
    name: "USA"
  },
  Algeria: {
    countryId: 99,
    name: "Canada"
  }
}

const countryOptions = () => {
  let countriesAtoH = {};
  Object.keys(countries).forEach((c) => {
    if (countries[c].countryId <= 97) {
      countriesAtoH[c] = countries[c];
    }
  });

  const options = Object.values(countriesAtoH).map((country) => {
    const c = {
      text: {
        type: "plain_text",
        text: country.name,
      },
      value: country.countryId
    }
    return c;
  });

  return options;
}

console.log(countryOptions());
```

Simply, you can use `Array.prototype.filter` and `Array.prototype.map` to get the `options`.

```js
const countries = {
  Afghanistan: {
    countryId: 0,
    name: "Afghanistan"
  },
  Albania: {
    countryId: 1,
    name: "USA"
  },
  Algeria: {
    countryId: 99,
    name: "Canada"
  }
}

const countryOptions = () => {
  const options = Object.values(countries).filter(({ countryId }) => countryId <= 97).map((item) => ({
    text: {
      type: "plain_text",
      text: item.name
    },
    value: item.countryId
  }));
  return options;
}

console.log(countryOptions());
```